# Django QueryDict OPTIONAL request method

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, http

I am using django 1.10.2 with python 3.5.2 in a Linux machine.

my Django app receive a request from client. The request method is identified as type OPTIONAL. I understand that Django automatically create a QueryDict for POST and GET request. So, how do I get the content of request that is not GET and POST Type? How can I create the QueryDict of such request or any other type of requests?

For debugging purposes, Is it possible to print the entire http request? body and headers? I would like to see the content of the request.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters are stored in request.body
You can convert them to normal python dict using this method:

```
def retrieve_parameters_for_optional(request):
    parameters = {}
    params_as_string = request.body.decode("utf-8")
    for param in params_as_string.split("&"):
        if "=" in param:
            key, value = param.split("=", 1)
            parameters[key] = value
    return parameters
```

You can just create QueryDict because it is immutable, 
but you can copy for example request.GET and clear() its content.

```
dict_of_parameters = retrieve_parameters_for_optional(request)
your_query_dict = request.GET.copy()
your_query_dict.clear()
for key, value in dict_of_parameters.items():
    your_query_dict[key] = value
```

After that you can for example assign your query_dict to request.GET and continue processing request just like normal GET request.

Comment: If the body is encoded as form data, you can simply do `parameters = QueryDict(request.body, encoding='utf-8')`, no need to copy and clear `request.GET`.